# How to compute Multicompare Tukey HSD in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, tukey

I am trying to compute a multicompare Tukey test with a list which contains 5 list of values (it is a list of lists). I was reading some documentation about `numpy.recarray` which it seems to fit in this topic but I don't really know how it works. 
Let's suppose that my list of lists is as follows:

```
my_list_of_lists = [[0.75,0.78,0.80,0.77,0.71,0.69,0.73],[0.76,0.73,0.88,0.71,0.72,0.80,0.72],[0.71,0.75,0.77,0.79,0.68,0.0.77,0.66],[0.72,0.79,0.82,0.73,0.75,0.60,0.72],[0.73,0.71,0.66,0.79,0.72,0.67,0.71]]
```

The output should be like this with 3 elements to compare:

```
Multiple Comparison of Means - Tukey HSD, FWER=0.05
============================================
group1 group2 meandiff  lower  upper  reject
--------------------------------------------
  0      1      1.5     0.3217 2.6783  True
  0      2      1.0    -0.1783 2.1783 False
  1      2      -0.5   -1.6783 0.6783 False
--------------------------------------------
```

Moreover, is there a way to plot the multicomparaison on means?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I found this page http://cleverowl.uk/2015/07/01/using-one-way-anova-and-tukeys-test-to-compare-data-sets/ but doesnt look to work for me

Comment: To get help here,  you need to specify a bunch of things. 1: what is the Tukey test? (i.e. specify your problem) 2: what did you try so far? (i.e. we're not going to solve your homework) 3: what exactly does your output mean?